# New Google Play Services 8.3 SignInButton broke the ability to get Birthday and first/last Name

Tags: android, google-play-services, googlesigninaccount

With the release of the [8.3 update](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/11/whats-new-in-google-play-services-83.html), it seems that the

Person class (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html)

that we used before is replaced with a

GoogleSignInAccount class (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount)

Both seems to be similar, we can still get the user Display Name (getDisplayname() method) to say hello, and customize the application, but the getName() and hasBirthday features are missing.

That's something that is necessary in the application to fill the register form automatically.

Are these informations (birthday and first/last name) completely missing from the new API, or is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure something out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Person resource now seems to be a part of Google+ API [plus.model.people](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#hasBirthday()) so in order to get social scopes, you would need to use the Google+ Sign In and `.addApi(Plus.API)` in GoogleApiClient.builder.

Simple `GoogleSignInAccount` only holds basic account information and if you are requesting social scopes, you need to include the red G+ sign in button (more information [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)).